# Javascript JQuery : Object doesn't support property or method 'toLowerCase'

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm building a dashboard with in Javascript with Crossfilter.

I'm using this function with Jquery:

```
   // d3's JSON call to grab the JSON data
        d3.json("universe.json", function(error, data) {
          // used by d3's dateFormat to parse the date correctly
          var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");

          // add map markers to map layer
          data.forEach( function(d,i) {

            d.date_e = dateFormat.parse(d.date_entered);
            d.date_i = dateFormat.parse(d.date_issued);


          });


  var tableDimension = xdata.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.pop.toLowerCase() + ' ' +
    d.City.toLowerCase() + ' ' +
    d.Province.toLowerCase() + ' ' +
    d.zip.toLowerCase() + ' ' +
    d.ward.toLowerCase();
});
```

This is a sample of my data:

**Error**:  SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'toLowerCase'

I am using the latest version of JQuery : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/external/jquery-2.0.2/jquery.js

```
[
  {
    "KMIST_TEMP_ID": "KTMPVN12119",
    "ID POP": "",
    "type": 2018,
    "pop": "No",
    "name": "Nha Thuoc An Binh",
    "Country": "",
    "Province": "Ho Chi Minh Province",
    "City": "Ho Chi Minh",
    "zip": "Thu Duc",
    "ward": "Linh Trung",
    "name_full": "Ho Chi Minh ,Nha Thuoc An Binh ,Thu Duc, Linh Trung",
    "latitude": 10.8539167,
    "longitude": 106.7716921,
    "geo": "106.7716921,10.8539167",
    "amenity": "pharmacy",
    "date_entered": "2015-10-30T00:00:00",
    "date_issued": "2015-10-30T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: What do you see if you console.log(d) in xdata.dimension?

Comment: I don't know which archive you use but the latest jQuery is 3.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if your d is your whole object which you write as your sample data then it is an array.so you have to manipulate your data with index.

```
var tableDimension = xdata.dimension(function(d) {
  return d[0].pop.toLowerCase() + ' ' +
    d[0].City.toLowerCase() + ' ' +
    d[0].Province.toLowerCase() + ' ' +
    d[0].zip.toLowerCase() + ' ' +
    d[0].ward.toLowerCase();
});
```

If it is not the case then all looks appropriate.try to remove one by one .toLowerCase() and check in which it is getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use d ["pop"] instead of d.pop and with all your keys. i am afraid that javascript doesn't make the difference between your keys and the dictionary functions.